# In Applescript, how can I get to the Help menu Search field, like Spotlight?

Tags: macos, search, applescript, menu, spotlight

In OS X, in order to quickly get at menu items from the keyboard, I want to be able to type a key combination, have it run a script, and have the script focus the Search field in the Help menu.  It should work just like the key combination for Spotlight, so if I run it again, it should dismiss the menu.  I can run the script with Quicksilver, but how can I write the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the script I came up with.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell (first process whose frontmost is true)
        click menu "Help" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Reminder: you *might* need GUI Scripting enabled before that script will run.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, hit cmd-? and don't mess with the script. :-)  That puts key focus in the help menu's search field.