# How can I get a list of menu items with Applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript

Is there any way to get a list of all the menu items under a menu heading like `File` or `Edit` with AppleScript?

I've found some related questions, but nothing exact. No luck on Google either.

I'm trying to get a list of which files are open in Photoshop's `Window` menu, and figure out which one has the check mark.

[image: screenshot-with-shadow.png]

I think I might be able to do the second part by using something like " [In Applescript, how can I find out if a menu item is selected/focused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69030/in-applescript-how-can-i-find-out-if-a-menu-item-is-selected-focused) " and the Accessibility Inspector since it has `AXMenuItemMarkChar`

[image: screenshot-with-shadow.png]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't have Photoshop but this works for Illustrator:

```
activate application "Adobe Illustrator"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Adobe Illustrator CS5.1"
        set xxx to name of every menu item of menu 1 of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

To get an attribute you can use:

```
activate application "Adobe Illustrator"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Adobe Illustrator CS5.1"
        set xxx to value of attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" of menu item "tools" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

nil scenario:

```
activate application "Adobe Illustrator"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Adobe Illustrator CS5.1"
        set xxx to value of attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" of menu item "Brushes" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1
        try
            xxx
        on error
            -- insert your code
            beep 2
        end try
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Sweet. Thank you! Now working on how to check if it is `nil` :)